# Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

Tags: eclipse

**problem occurs when I try to install new plugin in eclipse** from:

install new software.. from help menu and select site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars)

**error appears in detail:**

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars.
Unable  to read repositoryat
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201510021000/content.xml.xz.  
Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

**I try other solutions here but didn't work. what should I do?**

Comment: What kind of software you are trying to install? The link you provided does not belong to any downloadable software or plugin.

Comment: gui designer plugin .. java window builder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct link to download new Software via Help > Install New Software is:
[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180906210002/http://download.eclipse.org:80/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201506241200-1/4.5/).

```
Just copy above link and paste it in dialog box > Next > 
Review the items to be installed > Next > 
Accept the terms of license agreement > Finish
```

There you go, it's done.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!